# Counting Finger Swipes on Mobile in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've been looking around and can't find any information on whether or not you can track finger swipes in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. jQuery Mobile includes [swipe support](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)

```
$("#the_div_id_that_is_swiped").on("swipe", function(event) {
   // it has been swiped, so track it as an event
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Swipe', 'Landing Page Image', 'Description in here...']);
});
```